# how to query in string array types field in mysql sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, mysql2

I have tried many times, but I couldn't find the result. Anyone, please help me?
I have used sequlize and mysql2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgQDu.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1HMZ.png

Comment: Did you try `categories: { [Op.contains]: ['home']}`? And please add both code pieces as a formatted text instead of URLs to images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.